# Autocompletar condicionado usando JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Saludos, estoy desarrollando un formulario donde el usuario busca una plaza y un centro de trabajo mediante *Input Text* con función de ***Autocompletado*** en ***JQuery***, pero como son muchos registros en la base de datos, coloqué un *Select* que acorte la búsqueda. Sin embargo, no sé cómo enviarle el parámetro del *Select* al archivo de **PHP** donde hago la búsqueda y el autocompletado. Les dejo mi código comentado y de antemano muchas gracias.

**JQuery**

```
//Búsqueda de plazas
$(function() {
    $("#plaza").autocomplete({
        source: 'autocomplete.php',
    });
});   

//Búsqueda de centros de trabajo
$(function() {
    /$("#ct").autocomplete({
        source: 'autocompleteCT.php'
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<label>Selecci&oacute;n de nivel educativo:</label>
            <br />
            <select class="md-input" name="nivelE" id="nivelE" class="md-input-bar" onchange="nivelEduc()"> <!--Aquí se manda a un Javascript que retorna a un hidden con el valor del nivel seleccionado-->
                    <option value="ShowAll" selected="selected">Seleccione nivel:</option>
                    <option value="Inicial">Educaci&oacute;n Inicial</option> <!--DDI -->
                    <option value="PreescolarGeneral">Preescolar General</option>
                    <option value="PrimariaGeneral">Primaria General</option>
                    <option value="EBA">Educaci&oacute;n b&aacute;sica para adultos</option>
                    <option value="SecundariasGenerales">Secundarias Generales</option>
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" id="nivel" name="nivel" />
            <br />
                <label>Buscar la plaza vacante:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" class="md-input" name="plaza" id="plaza" value="">
                <br />
                <label>Clave de Centro de Trabajo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="md-input" name="ct" id="ct" />
```

**Autocompletado PHP**

```
//Obtener el término buscado
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
//Aquí pondría un switch o un if para hacer una consulta diferente, es  dependiendo de la opción del Select, es decir, si seleccionó preescolar, se consultarán sólo plazas y centros de trabajo de preescolar, etc. 
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM analitico WHERE estatus='V' and plaza LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY plaza ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['plaza'];
    }


    //Regresar el Json
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: El resultado de tu consulta en php la quieres mostrar en uno de los campos de texto?

Comment: Sí, la consulta, de hecho, es para que el usuario vaya tecleando la plaza o el centro de trabajo y le aparezcan las coincidencias. Eso ya lo hace pero quiero pasarle el parámetro del Select para que me acorte esas opciones en el campo de texto que se autocompleta. Por ejemplo, si seleccionas preescolar, que en plazas y en ct sólo muestre lo que corresponda a preescolar. La función de autocompletado sí me sirve, pero lo que no sé es cómo pasarle ese parámetro para hacer un switch o varios if donde se realicen las consultas. No sé si me explico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Primero te comento que no hace falta guardar en un input tipo hidden el valor seleccionado en tu select. Mediante JQuery puedes obtener este valor de la siguiente forma:

```
// Esta es una de las formas, existen otras
var nivel = $('#nivelE').find(':selected').val();
```

Entonces luego en tu función de autocompletado le envías este parámetro de la siguiente forma:

**JQuery**

```
//Búsqueda de plazas
$(function () {
$("#plaza").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'autocomplete.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        term: request.term,
        _nivel: nivel
      },
      success: function (data) {
        response(data);
      }
    });
  }
 });
});
```

Si te fijas envío por POST las variables por eso las capturo con $_POST y no con $_GET.

**AUTOCOMPLETADO PHP**

```
//Obtener el término buscado
$searchTerm = $_POST['term'];
$nivel = $_POST['_nivel'];

switch ($nivel) { 
  case "Inicial":
   //No se como se llama tu campo de nivel pero te dejo de ejemplo como 
   //sería la consulta
   $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM analitico WHERE estatus='V' and plaza" 
   ."LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' and nivelE = '".$nivel."' ORDER BY plaza ASC");                                                                                                             
  break;
  case "PreescolarGeneral":
      ....
  break;
  case "PrimariaGeneral":
     ....
  break;
  case "EBA":
    ...
  break;
  case "SecundariasGenerales":
   ...
  break;
 }

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['plaza'];
}


//Regresar el Json
echo json_encode($data);
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta! Estoy probado y por alguna razón, con el **POST** no me autocompleta y no sé por qué. Sigo probando con tu respuesta y de antemano ya llevas voto positivo. Saludos.

Comment: Que extraño. ¿Probaste enviarlo por GET?

Comment: Sí, con GET me funciona, sin embargo, la función del JQuery, así como me la pones, me manda error de sintaxis.

Comment: Ah, tienes razón. Ahí corregí la sintaxis. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

*** Ajax ***

```
function nivelEduc(){
    $nivelE = document.getElementById('nivelE').value;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "autocompletado.php",
    data: "term=" + $nivelE,
    success: function(html){
        /* llenamos el Select */
    }
});
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo añadiría eso al autocompletar.php? ¿O qué iría dentro del success? Una disculpa, no domino muy bien jquery

Comment: Recomiendo que añadas algo de explicación a tu respuesta para que el autor de la pregunta pueda entender tu idea. Saludos